# .NET Core Scaffold-Dbcontext without Identity Tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am trying out a project. I am using the Identity system in this project. First, I created Identity and DbContext by migrating to SQL Server. Now, create a table on SQL server and

```
scaffold-dbcontext "Server=localhost;Database=OrderSystemV;Trusted_Connection=true;TrustServerCertificate=True;" Microsoft.Entityframeworkcore.SqlServer -outputdir Models
```

When I type the Context is also refreshed and Identity's tables are also displayed. When the context is refreshed, the Identitydbcontext it inherits from is gone and it inherits from the normal DbContext. What command should I write to prevent this and to only show the newly created tables? My question is, is it normal to see tables like AspNetUser created by Identity?

Program.cs :

```
var connectionString = builder.Configuration["ConnectionStrings:AspnetRunConnection"];
builder.Services.AddDbContext<OrderSystemVContext>(options =>options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddIdentity<AppUser, AppRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<OrderSystemVContext>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-Tables` parameter to indicate which tables you want to include in scaffolding.

Refer to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/powershell#scaffold-dbcontext) for detailed information or other parameters.

Comment: Thank you. I want the context that will be created in this scaffold command to inherit IdentityDbContext, not dbcontext. How can I specify it as inheritance? So "public partial class OrderSystemVContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser, AppRole, int>" I want it to be like this. "OrderSystemVContext : DbContext" is not like that.

Comment: You can manually change it. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47577371/2892829) has more details.